# magento2 order status is still processing

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

When i create shipment and invoice for the order the status is still in processing through rest API Magento2.

The status is not changing to complete

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Have you  test on default magento 2?

Comment: Yes I have tested in Magento 2.2.6

Comment: Does Default Magento mean fresh Magento?

Comment: Yes amit it's fresh Magento

Comment: Please check Magento 2 Github, might you get the solution from their

Comment: Could you please share the link